# split punctuations without using regex

Tags: python-3.x, join, split, punctuation

Given input:

```
Democr _acy , is overrat _ed .
```

Desired output:

```
Democracy, is overrated.
```

Here is my code:

```
sentence=input()
punctuation = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~"
suffixes = ["acy", "ance", "ence", "dom", "er", "or", "ism", "ist",
             "ty", "ment", "ness", "ship", "sion", "tion", "ate",
            "en", "fy", "ize", "able", "ible", "al",
            "esque", "ful", "ic", "ous", "ish", "ive",
            "less", "ed", "ing", "ly", "ward", "wise"]
sentence_list = sentence.split('_')
c=""
if c not in punctuation:

 print("".join(sentence_list))
elif c in punctuation:
        for c in sentence:
         print("".join(sentence_list).split(c))
```

As you can see my output has 29 different list but I just want one of them.
I want to remove '*' from words and join punctuations and words which I removed '*' from it.
When I write a code like:

```
sentence_list = sentence.split('_')
print("".join(sentence_list))
```

'_' and punctuations disseapear.Where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would tackle this problem.

```
def combineSentence(si):
    punctuation = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~"
    rslt = ''
    ptr = 0
    while ptr < len(si):
        if si[ptr] not in punctuation and si[ptr] != '_':
            rslt += si[ptr]
        else:
            rslt = rslt[:-1]
            if si[ptr] in punctuation:
                rslt += si[ptr]
        ptr += 1   
    return rslt
```

executing `combineSentence('Democr _acy , is overrat _ed .')` will yield:

```
'Democracy, is overrated.'
```